# wasm how to compile existing js framework like vue,js

Tags: webassembly

I am looking to compile all my js modules to wasm to improve security.

This was i not only improve performance but also secure my codebase.

Can we programatically call the wasm complier from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compile a standard JavaScript codebase to WebAssembly. The closest you can get to this is to use AssemblyScript, which is a subset of TypeScript - however this is not a straightforward migration.

WebAssembly was never intended to be a compilation target for existing JavaScriot applications.

Comment: how can we encrypt the js modules and data at the lowest level .. so that we don't have to do it manually

Comment: @shrw WebAssembly is a separate target bytecode, it's not related to encryption of JavaScript in any way.